# express.js redirect can't set header after sent

Tags: node.js, express

I try to block access to a Json file by redirecting the user to the home page.

When trying to access to the file I get "can't set header after sent" even if that work.

I don't get this error if I remove `app.use(express.static(__dirname));`, but I don't know why.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname +'/index.html');
});

// Protect file
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.user == null && req.path === '/File.json')
    {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
    next(); 
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

Comment: `return res.redirect("/")`

Comment: It works, thanks, but why?

Comment: `return` stops the execution of the function. without `return` you got a response, but the function keeps executing the code till it reached `next()` witch moved to the next middleware to `app.use(express.static(__dirname))`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know. However, even with `return`, `next()` is called, which is good, but shouldn't it be skipped?

Comment: its not possible that `next()` is being executed if your code moves into the `if` statement that has an `return` inside of it. if the condition is not met then ofcorse the `if` block is skipped and `next()` is being executed

Comment: I say that because If I remove `next()` the page doesn't load. furthermore, without `express static` I can't load my css and images files so `express static` must be executed.

Comment: Perhaps `next()` confuses me. Maybe after `return` the second `app.use` is executed, but just not following the first `app.use` as the first `app.use` is "closed".

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are trying to set the header after the response `res.redirect('/')` is sent, express static is trying to set header to a response that's already sent

Answer (score 0):

That is because the `next` callback It is called event after you the `res.redirect`

```
// Protect file
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.user == null && req.path === '/File.json') {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
    next(); 
});
```

As you can see nothing prevent the execution of the `next` callback. to avoid that you can wrap it inside of a `if... else ...` statement or you can prepend a `return` before the `res.redirect`.

That means even if this condition `req.user == null && req.path === '/File.json'` is matched. the execution of all the block inside of the `IF` statement is executed as well as block which are outside the `IF` statement. So the `next` callback will be executed which will call the next middleware in the stack which is the `express.static` and by the way that middleware will try to render the `File.json` which reset the header after the redirect have been performed.